# java itext create pdf with hebrew (rtl) and english

Tags: pdf-generation, itext

I want to create a pdf document containg english and hebrew together , I can see hebrew letters by using: `BaseFont unicode = BaseFont.createFont("c:/windows/fonts/arialuni.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);`
but i see them in reverse. I want to be able to show the hebrew strings in rtl mode , and that the english strings will stay in ltr mode.

how can this be done? Is there an example of english and hebrew together? (or any other rtl languge).

Thank's In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to draw your text via an instance of ColumnText and get full BiDi support.  You just need to `setRunDirection` to something other than `PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_DEFAULT`.

You might be able to get the same effect with `ColumnText.showTextAligned()` using the longer version with a non-default run direction:

```
ColumnText.showTextAligned(contentByte, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, myParagraph, x, y, rotation,
  PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_LTR, 0);
```

This sets LTR as the default direction, and activates BIDI processing.  Within a `ColumnText`, `RUN_DIRECTION_DEFAULT` is the same as `RUN_DIRECTION_NO_BIDI`.

Comment: Thank you soooo much , you saved my day